# Error for graph saving loop - Must be length 1 (a summary value)

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to create and save graphs for individual organizations.  I keep getting an error that says "Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `Improved` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0"

The graphs work when I combine all the organizations together, so I'm not sure what is going on here!

Starting with this data:

```
library(ggpubr)
structure(list(Organization = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S"
), imp_imp20_Improved = c(55.6, 100, 50, 0, 57.1, 0, 0, 45, 50, 
60, 100, 50, 66.7, 66.7, 33.3, 0, 50, 0, 50)), row.names = c(NA, 
-19L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

org<- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S"
)
```

This is my code for the graph loop:

```
for(i in org) {
tiff(paste0("//graphs/",i,"_graph11.tiff"), units="in", width=3.5, height=3, res=300)

indicator_graph1<- indicators_ong %>% 
  filter(Organization==i) %>%
  summarise(Improved = imp_imp20_Improved,
            "Not Improved" = 100-imp_imp20_Improved)%>%
  gather(key="group") %>%
   arrange(desc(group))


labs <- paste0(indicator_graph1$group, "\n (", indicator_graph1$value,"%)")

z <- ggpie(indicator_graph1,"value",label=labs, fill= "group", color = "black", palette = c("darkgoldenrod1","azure3"), lab.pos = "in", lab.font = c(3,"black"),title="Improve 20")+ 
  theme(legend.position ="none")+
  font("title", size=10, hjust=0.5)

        print(z) 

dev.off()  
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code where you define `org` is missing. For reproducibility, could you please add?

Comment: I commented out the `tiff` part and the code ran fine, producing 19 plots. Does it work for you if you set `i <- "A"` and run the inner code?